# C# TryStartNoGCRegion 'The NoGCRegion mode was already in progress' exception when the GC is in LowLatency mode

Tags: c#, .net-core, garbage-collection

I'm trying to start a NoGCRegion. Before I do, I check to see if the GC is already in a NoGCRegion. My debugger says it isn't yet it still throws as if it was.
[image]
[image]
And here is the surrounding code for context:

```cs
        var firstTurn = true;
        GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.LowLatency;
        while (state0.Round < Constants.MAX_ROUNDS && state1.Round < Constants.MAX_ROUNDS)
        {
            Log($"GC Mode at begining: {GCSettings.LatencyMode}");
            if (GCSettings.LatencyMode != GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion) GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(15728640, true);
            var time = firstTurn ? 900 : 90;
            var action0 = mcts0.GetBest(state0, time);
            var action1 = mcts1.GetBest(state1, time);

            state0.Players[0].Action = action0;
            state0.Players[1].Action = action1;

            state1.Players[0].Action = action1;
            state1.Players[1].Action = action0;

            state0 = actionApplyer.ApplyActions(state0);
            state1 = actionApplyer.ApplyActions(state1);

            firstTurn = false;
            Log($"GC Mode at end: {GCSettings.LatencyMode}");

            if (GCSettings.LatencyMode == GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion) GC.EndNoGCRegion();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? And how come the runtime is saying that the NoCGRegion mode is in progress when I am checking that it isn't right before.

Comment: Have you tried entering `NoCGRegion` once, before entering the loop while you perform GC sensitive work? [`GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` doesn't like to be called while nested, or close together.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?view=net-5.0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75735794/13039722

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that that the code is calling TryStartNoGCRegion multiple times, in a nested fashion which the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?view=net-5.0) (remarks) advise against:

> You cannot nest calls to the TryStartNoGCRegion method, and you should
> only call the EndNoGCRegion method if the runtime is currently in no
> GC region latency mode. In other words, you should not call
> TryStartNoGCRegion multiple times (after the first method call,
> subsequent calls will not succeed), and you should not expect calls to
> EndNoGCRegion to succeed just because the first call to
> TryStartNoGCRegion succeeded.

The call to EndNoGCRegion doesn't happen because the GC is low latency mode:

> if (GCSettings.LatencyMode == GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion)
> GC.EndNoGCRegion();

So in the next iteration of the loop the code attempts to enter the NoGCRegion again and bonks out:

> if (GCSettings.LatencyMode != GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion)
> GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(15728640, true);

It is worth pointing out that the remarks in the docs offer a number of caveats about this type of functionality and about how it may not even work at all, even if the code calls it correctly.  Personally, I would try to find a solution that doesn't require interacting with the GC at all; a [mempool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) comes to mind.