# InvalidOperationException "NoGCRegion mode was already in progress" on call to GC.TryStartNoGCRegion

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm doing performance testing comparing various algorithms and want to eliminate the scatter in the results due to garbage collection perhaps being done during the critical phase of the test. I'm turning off the garbage collection using GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(long) (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?view=net-6.0) before the critical test phase and reactivating it immediately afterwards.

My code looks like this:

```
                    long allocatedBefore;
                    int collectionsBefore;
                    long allocatedAfter;
                    int collectionsAfter;
                    bool noGCSucceeded;
                    try
                        {
                            // Just in case end "no GC region"
                            if (GCSettings.LatencyMode == GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion)
                            {
                                GC.EndNoGCRegion();
                            }
                            // Exception is thrown sometimes in this line
                            noGCSucceeded = GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(solveAllocation);
                            allocatedBefore = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();
                            collectionsBefore = getTotalGCCollectionCount();
                            stopwatch.Restart();
                            doMyTest();
                            stopwatch.Stop();
                            allocatedAfter = GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();
                            collectionsAfter = getTotalGCCollectionCount();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            // Reactivate garbage collection
                            if (GCSettings.LatencyMode == GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion)
                            {
                                GC.EndNoGCRegion();
                            }
                        }
//...
        private int getTotalGCCollectionCount()
        {
            int collections = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < GC.MaxGeneration; i++)
            {
                collections += GC.CollectionCount(i);
            }
            return collections;
        }
```

The following exception is thrown from time to time (about once in 1500 tests):

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The NoGCRegion mode was already in progress
   bei System.GC.StartNoGCRegionWorker(Int64 totalSize, Boolean hasLohSize, Int64 lohSize, Boolean disallowFullBlockingGC)
   bei MyMethod.cs:Zeile 409.
   bei MyCaller.cs:Zeile 155.
```

The test might start a second thread that creates some objects it needs in a pool.

As far as I can see, the `finally` should always turn the GC back on, and the (theoretically unnecessary) check at the beginning should also do it in any case, but nevertheless, there is an error that NoGCRegion was already active.

The question [C# TryStartNoGCRegion 'The NoGCRegion mode was already in progress' exception when the GC is in LowLatency mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67542430/c-sharp-trystartnogcregion-the-nogcregion-mode-was-already-in-progress-excepti) got the same error message, but there was clear code path to have activated NoGCRegion more than once there. I can't see how that could happen here.

The test itself is not accessing GC operations except for  `GC.SuppressFinalize` in some Dispose() methods.

The test itself does not run in parallel with any other test; my `Main()` method loops over a set of input files and calls the test method for each one.

The test method uses an external c++ library which would be unmanaged memory in the .NET context.

What could be causing the exception, and why doesn't the call to `GC.EndNoGCRegion();` prevent the problem?

Comment: Is there any chance there is a multi-threaded operation here?

Comment: When you say "tests", are you aware that they run in parallel? This could easily be a race condition.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t use Benchmark.NET?

Comment: @Blindy: They are not unit tests, the tests do not run in parallel, my Main() routine loops over a set of input files and executes the tests one after the other. I want to avoid anything that would affect the timing.

Comment: @BronDavies: As I mentioned, the method under test can start additional threads.

Comment: @ckuri:  I'm not using Benchmark.NET simply because I didn't know about it, I'll have to read up.

Answer (score 1):

One way to reproduce the exception is to call GC.Collect in between the calls of GC.TryStartNoGCRegion and GC.EndNoGCRegion. That seems to put the whole thing into a limbo-state where GCSettings.LatencyMode is already reset, but the other related methods still think that the NoGCRegion has not been left yet:

```
bool noGCRegionEntered = false;
if (GCSettings.LatencyMode != GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion)
    noGCRegionEntered = GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(320000000, 160000000, false);

try
{
    // Causes GCSettings.LatencyMode to be reset to GCLatencyMode.Interactive.
    // If you call GC.EndNoGCRegion afterwards (regardless of the new 
    // GCSettings.LatencyMode), it throws a System.InvalidOperationException:
    // 'Garbage collection was induced in NoGCRegion mode' - which is probably expected.
    // If you don't call GC.EndNoGCRegion, the next call of GC.TryStartNoGCRegion throws an 
    // System.InvalidOperationException: 'The NoGCRegion mode was already in progress'.
    // So it seems that the NoGCRegion has not been left despite the fact that 
    // GCSettings.LatencyMode is already back to GCLatencyMode.Interactive.
    // If you then call GC.TryStartNoGCRegion again, it succeeds again.
    // It also succeeds if you call it after calling GC.EndNoGCRegion even though the latter
    // threw the exception 'Garbage collection was induced in NoGCRegion mode'. 
    GC.Collect();
}
finally
{
    if (noGCRegionEntered)
        if (GCSettings.LatencyMode == GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion)
            GC.EndNoGCRegion();
}
```

So, I suspect that doMyTest or anything called directly or indirectly from it might call GC.Collect intermittently.

To find out who performs this call, you could use the Events Viewer tool in Visual Studio Profiler which logs ETW events.

[image: Visual Studio Profiler - EventsViewer]
Be sure to activate at least "GC" under Common Providers/.NET Runtime and select "Collect Events and Stacks" in the dropdown.

After finishing the profiler session, filter the result by the event name "GC/Trigered", and look for a row having the reason "Induced":

[image]

I wonder whether this limbo-state could also be entered for other reasons, e.g. "InducedLowMemory":

> InducedLowMemory – GC subscribes to the low memory notification from the OS and when the OS notifies us that “the memory is low on the machine” a GC is induced; or if this is a hosted process and the host indicates we are low on memory, we also induce a GC.

Source: [GC ETW Events – 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/gc-etw-events-3/)